# Python and pytest - check if a test passes or fails and execute code

Tags: python, pytest

I'm doing test automation with python and we have a test management tool. What we try to do is update the test cases in this management tool so that if a test fails the guys here can see it very quickly.

But the thing is that I can't figure out when I test has passed or failed. So my tests looks like this:

```
@decorator(testId = 5, comment = "Test fails or not")
    def test(self):
        # assert
        assert True == False
```

No i'm trying to solve it with a decorator but it didn't work out. So this test will fail and now I need to push that to a test management system online. Anybody a clue on how to do this? My decorator code looks like this:

```
def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Inside decorator")
    def inner(func):
        print("testId: ", kwargs["testId"])
        if "comment" in kwargs.keys():
            print("comment: ", kwargs["comment"])
        try:
            pass
        except AssertionError as assertionError:
            print("Assertion fails: " + str(assertionError))
            raise
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Something else failed")
            print("exception: " + str(ex))
            raise
        finally:
            print("ending")
        return func
    return inner
```

Comment: I feel that the test function is wrong. How can True == False?

Comment: I guess/think, that this is an example of a test that should always fail

Comment: It is an example to trigger an assert exception :-)

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while, I made a better decorator. It looks like this:

```
import functools

def exception(function):
  @functools.wraps(function)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
      return function(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
      print("error in: " + function.__name__)
      raise
  return wrapper

@exception
def zero_divide():
    1 / 1
    a = AnObjectTHatDOESNTEXIST()

print("start")
zero_divide()
print("end")
```